# How can I create an Array method in Swift similar to sort, filter, reduce, and map?

Tags: swift, methods, types, closures

I have a question, during study of closure.

I want make datatypes closure method like in array types
 .sort(), .filter(), .reduce(), .map()

But how can I make this things.
Its datatype not a class.

---

I want make

```
array.somemethod({closure})
```

not a

```
Somefunc(input: array, closure : { .... })
```

-

Can I make datatype method in swift?

otherwise, I can use func only?

Comment: Most datatypes in Swift are structures. Arrays, Strings, Doubles, Ints, Dates. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Leo Dabus Hmm..., I want make like array.somemethod({closure}) , not a Somefunc(input: array, closure : { .... })

Comment: You just need extend Array and pass a closure as your method argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need extend Array and pass a closure as your method argument. Lets say you would like to create a mutating method to work as the opposite of filter (to remove elements of your array based on a condition):

```
extension Array {
    mutating func removeAll(where isExcluded: (Element) -> Bool)  {
        for (index, element) in enumerated().reversed() {
            if isExcluded(element) {
                remove(at: index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another option extending `RangeReplaceableCollection`:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self: BidirectionalCollection {
    mutating func removeAll(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows {
        for index in indices.reversed() where try predicate(self[index]) {
            remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30]
array.removeAll(where: {$0 > 5})
print(array)   // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

or using trailing closure syntax

```
array.removeAll { $0 > 5 }
```