# Swift: Better way to remove a specific Object from an array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to be more efficient with my code, but I'm having a brain fart. This code I wrote works great, and does exactly what I need it to do: It checks an array and removes an Object at an unknown Index. But I feel there is a better, more efficient way to write it. I went to Array.remove(at:) but that requires a known index. I'm getting into big O notation and don't know how to make this easier to process. Any ideas?

```
 // create a new object array
 var sort : [MyCustomObject] = []

//iterate through my object array  

        for i in objectArray{
            if i === objectToRemove{
            }
            else{
                sort.append(i)
            }
        }

     // set old array to sort, which no longer has the unwanted object 
        self.objectArray = sort
```

Comment: Use `index(where:)` to find the index of the object to remove. Then, `remove(at:)` to remove it.

Comment: While it isn't the best answer to your question, note that you could use the `!==` operator to clean up that if statement.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`firstIndex(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex) (previously called `index(where:)` in **Swift 4.1** and earlier) to search the array for your object using the predicate `{ $0 === objectToRemove }`, then call [`remove(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641390-remove) on the array to remove it:

```
if let idx = objectArray.firstIndex(where: { $0 === objectToRemove }) {
    objectArray.remove(at: idx)
}
```

This allows you to search for your object whether it is `Equatable` or not.

Comment: Note that firstIndex(where:) still in beta (formerly known as `index(where:)`)

Comment: @LeoDabus, thanks for the note.  I'm having trouble finding a link for `index(where:)` Apple documentation.

Comment: I couldn't find it either.

Comment: In the end, your answer was the cleanest and easiest code to implement without making my CustomObject Equatable. Thank you! I have also checked the apple documentation for          index(where:)      and have not been able to find anything. But it works!

Comment: Though Swift 4.1, `index(where:)` was the call.  Apple just updated the documentation before Swift 4.2 was released (really soon now).

Answer (score 13):

If you are coding with Xcode 10.0+ beta (Swift 4.2 or later) you can use the new method [`removeAll(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017532-removeall)

```
mutating func removeAll(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows
```

> **Discussion:** Use this method to remove every element in a collection
> that meets particular criteria.
> **Complexity: O(n), where n is the length of the collection.**

> This example removes all the odd
> values from an array of numbers:

**Swift 5.2 or later**

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    var isEven: Bool { isMultiple(of: 2) }
    var isOdd: Bool { !isMultiple(of: 2) }
}

var numbers = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
numbers.removeAll(where: \.isOdd) // numbers == [6, 8, 10]
numbers
```

---

In your case make sure `MyCustomObject` conforms to `Equatable`

```
objectArray.removeAll(where: { $0 == objectToRemove })
```

or use one of its properties that does conform to it as the predicate (i.e `id: Int`):

```
objectArray.removeAll(where: { $0.id == idToRemove })
```

---

**Note:** If you are not using Xcode 10.0+ beta (Swift 4.2) you can implement your own `removeAll(where:)` method as you can see in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48016789/2303865).

---

Implementing a `removeFirst(where:)` and `removeLast(where:)` to avoid iterating the whole Collection as mentioned in comments by @vacawama

**Swift 4.1**

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection  {
    @discardableResult
    mutating func removeFirst(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Element?  {
        guard let index = try index(where: predicate) else { return nil }
        return remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self: BidirectionalCollection {
    @discardableResult
    mutating func removeLast(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Element? {
        guard let index = try indices.reversed().first(where: {
            try predicate(self[$0])
        }) else { return nil }
        return remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

---

**Swift 4.2 or later** (as suggested by @Hamish)

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    @discardableResult
    mutating func removeFirst(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Element? {
        guard let index = try firstIndex(where: predicate) else { return nil }
        return remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self: BidirectionalCollection {
    @discardableResult
    mutating func removeLast(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Element? {
        guard let index = try lastIndex(where: predicate) else { return nil }
        return remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

You can also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62306093/2303865) for a remove(while:), removeLast(while:) and  dropLast(while:) method implementations.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this generic to remove any kind of object From array

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
mutating func removeObject(object: Element)  {
    if let index = firstIndex(of: object) {
        remove(at: index)
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if let ind = objectArray.index(of:objectToRemove) {
  objectArray.remove(at:ind)
}
```

Comment: Thank You! I tried that but i get 'Cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: MyCustomObject)'. I think that does not work because its a custom object?

Comment: **class YourClass:Equatable** {  }

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

Use `enumerated()` and you will have the index:

```
var array = ["a","b","c"]
let objectToRemove = "b"
for (index, value) in array.enumerated() {
    if value == objectToRemove {
        array.remove(at: index)
    }
}
print(array) // Prints: ["a","c"]
```

Edit:

Or maybe better yet, use filter:

```
var array = ["a","b","c"]
let objectToRemove = "b"
array = array.filter { $0 != objectToRemove } // Keeps only what is
                                              // different from the 
                                              // objectToRemove
print(newArray)  // Prints: ["a","c"]
```

Comment: You are right! I will just let `for in` example because it's easier for beginners to understand ;-) Thank you very much Leo Dabus!

Comment: `enumerate` and remove will cause `Index out of range`