# Remove last elements of a collection while a condition in Swift

Tags: swift

I am attempting to remove `""` & `" "` from the back of a string array until the last item contains some text, but my implementation isn't picking up `" "`.

My implementation so far:

```
var array = ["A", "B", "", "C", "D", " ", " ", ""]

while true {
    if (array.last == " " || array.last == "") {
        array.removeLast()
    } else {
        break
    }
}
```

My desired output is

```
["A", "B", "", "C", "D"]
```

, but my current output is

```
["A", "B", "", "C", "D", " ", " "]
```

, where the `while` loop simply `breaks` after encountering `" "`

Any advice why is it not picking up the `" "`?

Comment: You may just move your condition to `while` instead of `true`.

Comment: It actually works without problems for me.

Comment: I just tried it on an playground and the output was `["A", "B", "", "C", "D"]` so your code works as you want

Comment: Use for loop reversed.  You can't use do while in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve this is to reverse the collection (which is done lazily) and drop the unwanted items until you encounter the wanted ones. Afterwards, reverse the collection again.

```
let array = ["A", "B", "", "C", "D", " ", " ", ""]

let filtered = array.reversed().drop(while: {
    $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty
}).reversed() as [String]

print(filtered) // "["A", "B", "", "C", "D"]\n"
```

Note that the check for `" "` may fail if it's not a normal space, for example a non-breaking space (Unicode checkpoint U+00A0). This may be the issue you're having in the first place. So trim the string (it removes characters from the start and end only) and check whether the result is an empty string.

Comment: if you decide to reverse the array, you might want to use `drop(while:)`. `filter` is just not a good choice here.

Comment: @Sulthan: Oooh, nice! Thanks a lot for making me aware of this, that makes for a much nicer solution!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why they have `drop(while:)` and did not implement `dropLast(while:)`. The implementation bellow works on any collection:

```
extension Collection {
    func dropLast(while predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> SubSequence {
        guard let index = try indices.reversed().first(where: { try !predicate(self[$0]) }) else {
            return self[startIndex..<startIndex]
        }
        return self[...index]
    }
}
```

---

```
"123".dropLast(while: \.isWholeNumber)    // ""
"abc123".dropLast(while: \.isWholeNumber) // "abc"
"123abc".dropLast(while: \.isWholeNumber) // "123abc"
```

And extending RangeReplaceableCollection we can implement `remove(while:)` and `removeLast(while:)` as well:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
     mutating func remove(while predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows {
        guard let index = try indices.first(where: { try !predicate(self[$0]) }) else {
            removeAll()
            return
        }
        removeSubrange(..<index)
    }
    mutating func removeLast(while predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows {
        guard let index = try indices.reversed().first(where: { try !predicate(self[$0]) }) else {
            removeAll()
            return
        }
        removeSubrange(self.index(after: index)...)
    }
}
```

---

```
var string = "abc123"
string.removeLast(while: \.isWholeNumber)
string  // "abc"

var string2 = "abc123"
string2.remove(while: \.isLetter)
string2 // "123"

var array = ["A", "B", "", "C", "D", " ", " ", ""]
array.removeLast { $0 == "" || $0 == " " }
array  // ["A", "B", "", "C", "D"]
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `return self[startIndex..<endIndex]`?

Comment: @mgray88 this would return the whole collection subsequence (same as `self[...]`). I am returning an empty collection

Answer (score 4):

Move your condition to `while` and make sure you're checking on the correct array after the operation.

```swift
var array = ["A", "B", "", "C", "D", " ", " ", ""]

while array.last == " " || array.last == "" {
    array.removeLast()
}

print(array) // ["A", "B", "", "C", "D"]
```

Comment: User want to remove only the one at the ends, not the one between B and C.

Comment: Hey, I think this solution is actually better than using `while true`. Voted.

Comment: I like your answer, better place the condition inside the while instead of while true

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, lets extend `Array` with this functionality in a generic way while also externally providing the condition for more flexibility.

Similar to `Array`s having a `drop(while:)`, we can make a `dropLast(while:)` like so:

```
extension Array {
    func dropLast(while handler: (Element)->Bool) -> Array {
        var array = self
        while let last = array.last, handler(last) {
            array.removeLast()
        }
        return array
    }
}
```

---

#### Usage Example:

```
let array = ["", "A", "B", "", "C", "D", " ", " ", ""]
let modified = array.dropLast { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty }
print(modified) //["", "A", "B", "", "C", "D"]
```

---

#### Bonus:

It can handle other types of arrays too, and since the condition is not baked into the functionality, it's flexible and reusable.

```
let array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, -1, 0, -2]

//Drop (from tail) all numbers less than 1
let modified = array.dropLast(while: { (val) -> Bool in
    return val < 1
})
print(modified) //[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically your solution plays fine. But you can make it more generic for "", " ", "", "  ", .... :

```
import Foundation
var array = ["A", "B", "", "C", "D", " ", " ", ""]
while true {
    let shouldRemoveLast = array.last?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty ?? false
    if (shouldRemoveLast) { array.removeLast() } else { break }
}
```

Comment: And again, `while true { if condition { something() } else { break } }` is identical to `while condition { something() }`

Comment: @user28434: yes you're right. But I was following close to the questioner coding style. btw the new way is: `while array.last?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty ?? false { array.removeLast() }`

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's a one liner, functional programming style, extension, that removes the last elements that satisfy the given criteria:

```swift
extension Collection {
    func dropLast(while predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> SubSequence {
        indices.reversed().first { !predicate(self[$0]) }.map(prefix(through:)) ?? prefix(0)
    }
}
```

Same code, but in a more imperative style:

```swift
extension Collection {
    func dropLast(while predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> SubSequence {
        if let lastValidIndex = indices.reversed().first(where: { !predicate(self[$0]) }) {
            return prefix(through: lastValidIndex)
        } else {
            return prefix(0)
        }
    }
}
```